# Solving linear system of equations with Prolog library Simplex

Tags: prolog, linear-programming, swi-prolog, simplex

I am trying to use SWI-Prolog [simplex library](https://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc/_SWI_/library/clp/simplex.pl) to solve a linear system of equations with the set of real numbers as domain. Would anyone please have a clue why the following query does not succeed?

```
maximize(
[],
state(
 0,
 [],
 [ 
   c(0,
    [- 0.95*x(3),0.05*x(0),0.05*x(1),0.05*x(2)],
    =,
    1479754163278877r9007199254740992),
   c(0,
    [0.95*x(2),- 0.05*x(0),- 0.05*x(1),- 0.05*x(3)],
    =,
    185786871969449310676024028079063r3975352282315727403093661252059136
   ),
   c(0,
    [0.95*x(1),- 0.05*x(0),- 0.05*x(2),- 0.05*x(3)],
    =,
    756128230024134313216574233897861r15901409129262909612374645008236544
   ),
   c(0,
    [0.95*x(0),- 0.05*x(1),- 0.05*x(2),- 0.05*x(3)],
    =,
    294112628726237r72057594037927936
   )
 ],
 []
),
S).
```

The system I intend to solve is the following:

```
0.05*x(0)+0.05*x(1)+0.05*x(2)-0.95*x(3)
= 
1479754163278877/9007199254740992

- 0.05*x(0)- 0.05*x(1)+0.95*x(2)- 0.05*x(3) 
=
185786871969449310676024028079063/3975352282315727403093661252059136

- 0.05*x(0)+0.95*x(1)- 0.05*x(2)- 0.05*x(3)
=
756128230024134313216574233897861/15901409129262909612374645008236544

0.95*x(0)- 0.05*x(1)- 0.05*x(2)- 0.05*x(3)
=
294112628726237/72057594037927936
```

Alternatively, would you please know a better way to solve this in Prolog?

Comment: Likely the simplex solver assumes all variables are non-negative. Could that be tripping you up?

Comment: thanks for the suggestion! it seems only the right hand side of constraints must be non-negative https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=constraint/3

Comment: I see: " In the current implementation, all variables are implicitly constrained to be non-negative. This may change in future versions, and non-negativity constraints should therefore be stated explicitly."

Comment: Thanks a lot, well spotted! would you please know a more appropriate way to solve this kind of linear systems of equations with Prolog?

Comment: I don't know much about SWI-Prolog and this package (so no clue about other linear system solvers), but the LP formulation may be salvageable by "variable splitting". Too long to explain in a comment, but this will allow you to reformulate the original problem in terms of just non-negative variables.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the solver assumes all variables are non-negative. So the question becomes: can we reformulate `Ax=b`, where `x` are free variables, into something that uses non-negative variables? The answer is: yes. Using a technique called variable splitting we can replace each `x(j)` by `xplus(j)-xmin(j)` where `xplus(j),xmin(j)>=0`. So the system of equations becomes:

```
  sum(j, a(i,j)*(xplus(j)-xmin(j))) = b(i)   for all i
  xplus(j),xmin(j)>=0
```

We may need to make sure that only one of the pair `(xplus(j),xmin(j))` can become nonzero. This may hold automatically as the basis matrix B will become singular if both are in the basis. But we also can set an objective that handles this:

```
  min sum(j, xplus(j)+xmin(j))
```

As long as the system of equations has a feasible solution, the objective will make sure that only one of `(xplus(j),xmin(j))` is nonzero.